# How to get all records with a jsonb field timestamp that matches Sunday or Saturday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I want to extract all records that match `start_date` field in json column `request` to fall in either Saturday or Sunday.

tried this

```
Foo.where("extract(dow from request->>'start_date') ?| array[5.0, 6.0]")
```

getting error `ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, text) does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `CAST` your value to `DATE` just before `EXTRACT`:

```
Foo.where("extract(dow from CAST(request->>'start_date' AS DATE)) IN(5.0, 6.0)")
```

Comment: thanks. cast works now. but is `?|` correct operator I'm using? 
`Foo.where("extract(dow from CAST(request->>'start_date' AS DATE)) = 6 ")` works. but `Foo.where("extract(dow from CAST(request->>'start_date' AS DATE)) ?| array[5.0, 6.0] ")` throws `No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.` Not sure which argument needs to be casted to what.. error seems not so verbose :(

Comment: You can use `IN`operator, it's less verbose than using an array operator. See my updated answer.